# SVG leaving "traces" on Webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to use the following SVG animation in my project:
https://codepen.io/ChipD/pen/KoXzda

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
/* Housekeeping CSS */
body {
  background: #272822 !important;
}

.loader-container {
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:25vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* 
Hiding the rect on page load 
And add the "expand" animation
*/
rect {
  opacity:0;
  animation: expand 0.2s forwards;
}
/* End of housekeeping css */xs

/* Delays to subsequent "dashes" */
#line1 #dash-2 {
  animation-delay:0.1s;
}

#line1 #dash-3 {
  animation-delay:0.2s;
}

#line1 #dash-4 {
  animation-delay:0.3s;
}

#line2 #dash-1 {
  animation-delay:0.4s;
}

#line2 #dash-2 {
  animation-delay:0.5s;
}

#line2 #dash-3 {
  animation-delay:0.6s;
}

#line3 {
  animation-delay:0.7s;
}

#line4 {
  animation-delay:.8s;
}

#line5 {
  animation-delay:0.9s;
}

#line6 {
  animation-delay:1s;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% { opacity: 1; width: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1; width: 1 }
}

#group1 {
  animation: scroll 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {transform: translateY(initial)}
  100% {transform: translateY(-165px)}
}

#group2 {
  transform: translateY(165px);
  animation: scroll2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 text-center loader-container">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="400px" height="165px" viewBox="0 0 400 165" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 43.2 (39069) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>Artboard</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="coding" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard">
            <g id="group1">
                <g id="line1">
                    <rect id="dash-1" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-2" fill="#A6E22E" x="43" y="0" width="60" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-3" fill="#FFE792" x="106" y="0" width="100" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-4" fill="#FFE792" x="209" y="0" width="70" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                </g>
                <g id="line2" transform="translate(30.000000, 27.000000)">
                    <rect id="dash-1" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-2" fill="#A6E22E" x="43" y="0" width="60" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-3" fill="#FFE792" x="106" y="0" width="80" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                </g>
                <rect id="line6" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="135" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line3" fill="#F8F8F2" x="60" y="54" width="290" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line4" fill="#F8F8F2" x="60" y="81" width="225" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line5" fill="#F92672" x="30" y="108" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
            </g>
          <g id="group2">
                <g id="line1">
                    <rect id="dash-1" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-2" fill="#A6E22E" x="43" y="0" width="60" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-3" fill="#FFE792" x="106" y="0" width="100" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-4" fill="#FFE792" x="209" y="0" width="70" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                </g>
                <g id="line2" transform="translate(30.000000, 27.000000)">
                    <rect id="dash-1" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-2" fill="#A6E22E" x="43" y="0" width="60" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                    <rect id="dash-3" fill="#FFE792" x="106" y="0" width="80" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                </g>
                <rect id="line6" fill="#F92672" x="0" y="135" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line3" fill="#F8F8F2" x="60" y="54" width="290" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line4" fill="#F8F8F2" x="60" y="81" width="225" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
                <rect id="line5" fill="#F92672" x="30" y="108" width="40" height="20" rx="10"></rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

My actual project:  https://cryptodescriptor.github.io/portfolio/

The issue:
[Here is an image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UFEo.png)

It might be hard to tell from the image above.. But if you head over to the codepen or github.io link on any Webkit browser you will see slight colour tracing (mainly occurs at the edges of the SVG)

Was wondering if there is any plausible solution?

Comment: Can't repro here on Safari 14.0

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by rewriting the whole CSS code to use masks rather than rectangle width transformations, as well as removing any timing offsets on "group2".